# Gitlab CI error when building maven image using jib: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, unlink /target/node/.nfs000000007cb56ba90067282d

Tags: java, docker, maven, gitlab-ci, nfs

When running:

`./mvnw package -Pprod verify -DskipTests jib:build -Djib.to.image=$IMAGE_TAG -Djib.to.auth.username=gitlab-ci-token  -Djib.to.auth.password=$CI_BUILD_TOKEN -Dmaven.repo.local=$MAVEN_USER_HOME`

I get an error that says:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, unlink '/builds/PATH/target/node/.nfs000000007cb56ba90067282d'
```

It happens when `./mvnw package` reaches:

```
[INFO] > ng build --configuration production
[INFO] 
[INFO] An unhandled exception occurred: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, unlink '/builds/sharing/codeability-sharing-platform/target/node/.nfs000000007cb56ba90067282d'
```

I have tried all possible solutions from here: [Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, rmdir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55212864/error-ebusy-resource-busy-or-locked-rmdir)

However, none of these solutions worked because they are not executed in a pipeline and during the mvnw package command.

Comment: Running build on a NFS share is a problem... also why using `package` as well as `verify` ? Use only `verify` (check the build life cycle)...BTW: Which version of Maven do you use?

Comment: Thank you for your answer !
I am using wrapper/dists/apache-maven-3.8.3 and Java version: 11.0.15