# Problem with publishing electron app for windows when using github workflows

Tags: electron, electron-forge

I'm trying to publish the app, using "electron-forge publish" command.

Everything works fine for mac & linux but not for windows, this is part of my .yml file that's causing the issue,:

```yaml
publish_on_win:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2       
    - uses: actions/setup-node@master
      with:
        node-version: 14
    - name: install dependencies
      run: npm ci
    - name: clean npm cache
      run: npm cache clean --force
    - name: publish
      env:
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.TOKEN }}
      run: npm run publish
```

Basically everything goes alright up to this part:

> [STARTED] Making a squirrel distributable for win32/x64

and then it runs 'till I cancel the workflow. After that, that's the error I see in the logs:

```
Fail to clean temporary files on exit :  Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, unlink 'C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\si-2023319-3264-ho6ipb.02ga\electron_publish_example.1.0.16.nupkg'
    at Object.unlinkSync (fs.js:1256:3)
    at rimrafSync (D:\a\accounting-dash\accounting-dash\node_modules\temp\node_modules\rimraf\rimraf.js:306:17)
    at D:\a\accounting-dash\accounting-dash\node_modules\temp\node_modules\rimraf\rimraf.js:342:5
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at rmkidsSync (D:\a\accounting-dash\accounting-dash\node_modules\temp\node_modules\rimraf\rimraf.js:341:26)
    at rmdirSync (D:\a\accounting-dash\accounting-dash\node_modules\temp\node_modules\rimraf\rimraf.js:334:7)
    at rimrafSync (D:\a\accounting-dash\accounting-dash\node_modules\temp\node_modules\rimraf\rimraf.js:304:9)
    at cleanupDirsSync (D:\a\accounting-dash\accounting-dash\node_modules\temp\lib\temp.js:180:5)
    at cleanupSync (D:\a\accounting-dash\accounting-dash\node_modules\temp\lib\temp.js:232:19)
    at process.<anonymous> (D:\a\accounting-dash\accounting-dash\node_modules\temp\lib\temp.js:109:13)
    at process.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at process.emit (domain.js:475:12)
    at process.exit (internal/process/per_thread.js:179:15)
    at process.<anonymous> (D:\a\accounting-dash\accounting-dash\node_modules\listr2\dist\index.cjs:1229:17)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:520:26)
    at process.emit (events.js:412:35) {
  errno: -4082,
  syscall: 'unlink',
  code: 'EBUSY',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\RUNNER~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\si-2023319-3264-ho6ipb.02ga\\electron_publish_example.1.0.16.nupkg'
}
```

The only idea I had to resolve the issue is adding "pm cache clean" to the script.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using visual studio code terminal? Because I had the exact same issue. I tried running my commands with windows powershell and it executed perfectly. I hope that can solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the advice but the thing is, I'm not running it locally. It's being executed remotely on github.

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1

Maybe [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62910851/10223524) can help?

```
npm cache verify
```

### Option 2

There's also [another solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62953905/10223524) from the same thread:

```
npm cache clean

npm install --cache
```